# How often should I create a 'system image'?

Tags: windows-7, backup

I have a Windows 7 PC and back up weekly. This seems like a reasonable schedule for file backups, but how often should I create a system image backup; which takes several hours to complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backing up once a week is an excellent start.  As for imaging, I would recommend that you do it monthly, and store them on an external drive.  Each month, when you create a new image, delete the image from two months before, and keep last month's and the current month (in case something goes wrong, etc redundancy is good).

[**System Restore**](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/system-restore) points are somewhat similar to images and are extremely useful and much quicker to set and use.  Consider it an alternative or for what its worth.